# Detecting collision between two rectangles on a WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, collision-detection

I am extremely new to programming, and I have started off with `C#`. I am now trying to make my first game, I decided on snake. So far I have been trying to research this question, but all of the answers I see are ones that pertain to people who are using a different method of moving their snake around.

My program uses two doubles (`left` and `top`) in order to store where the snake is on the `Canvas`. My program also uses two doubles for the "food" in the game, called `randomFoodSpawnLeft` and `randomFoodSpawnTop`.

My question is this. How does one detect collision between two rectangular objects with just a left and top value? I am rather confused.

`snakeWindow` is the Window, `snakeHead` is the rectangle that represents a snake, `left` is the left value of the snake, `top` is the top value of the snake.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double left = Canvas.GetLeft(snakeHead);
        double top = Canvas.GetTop(snakeHead);

        if (keyUp)
        {
            top -= 3;
        }
        else if (keyDown)
        {
            top += 3;
        }
        else if (keyLeft)
        {
            left -= 3;
        }

        else if (keyRight)
        {
            left += 3;
        }
        // These statements see if you have hit the border of the window, default is 1024x765
        if (left < 0)
        {
            left = 0;
            gameOver = true;
        }
        if (top < 0)
        {
            top = 0;
            gameOver = true;
        }
        if (left > snakeWindow.Width)
        {
            left = 0;
            gameOver = true;
        }
        if (top > snakeWindow.Height)
        {
            top = 0;
            gameOver = true;
        }
        // Statements that detect hit collision between the snakeHead and food
        //
        if (foodEaten == true)
        {
            spawnFood();
            textBlockCurrentScore.Text += 1;
        }

            // If gameOver were to be true, then the game would have to end. In order to accomplish this I display to the user that the game is over
            // and the snakeHead is disabled, and should restart.
            if (gameOver == true)
        {
            keyRight = false;
            keyLeft = false;
            keyUp = false;
            keyDown = false;
            top = 0;
            left = 0;

            textBlockGameOver.Text = "GAME OVER!";
            snakeCanvas.Background = Brushes.Blue;
        }


        Canvas.SetLeft(snakeHead, left);
        Canvas.SetTop(snakeHead, top);
    }
```

Comment: You could use the `IntersectsWith` method of `Rectangle` to check for a collision: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Instead of four `if`'s one can use just one to do hit-test (see [intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0(v=vs.110).aspx)). Question is unclear: every rectangle have coordinates (Left, Top) and dimensions (Width, Height). What is the problem?

Comment: So what am I to do with the Left, Top, Width, and Height? How does one compare the snake with the food? Is that all I need to do an intersectsWith?

Comment: As long as both the snakehead and the food are rectangles, you can just to `snakeHead.IntersectsWith(food)` to test if they have collided.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tried the IntersectsWith, it said that Rectangle does not contain a definition for intersectsWith.

Comment: `IntersectsWith` is a method on `System.Drawing.Rectangle`; maybe you are using `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle`?

Comment: Yes, I believe that I am using a Shapes.Rectangle, in that case how would you detect collision with a Shapes?

Comment: I'd create a [`Rect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect(v=vs.110).aspx) for the head and food and use `IntersectsWith`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`System.Windows.Rect.IntersectsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.rect.intersectswith). Try it like this:

```
Rect rect1 = new Rect(left1, top1, widht1, height1);
Rect rect2 = new Rect(left2, top2, widht2, height2);

bool intersects = rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2);
```

Of course you will have to check the snake's head against all it's parts.

Comment: If you store the body parts as a list of `Rect`s, you can do the nice LINQ statement: `eatenSelf = bodyParts.Any(part => snakeHead.IntersectsWith(part));`

Comment: I get an error when trying to declare "System.Windows.Rect.IntersectsWith" It tells me Rect is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: @Cinnamonbun the type is `System.Windows.Rect`. `IntersectsWith` is an instance method of that type.

Comment: @RenéVogt I see, however it is now telling me that No overload for method 'IntersectsWith' takes 2 arguments.

Comment: @Cinnamonbun please my answer again carefully. I don't call it with two arguments. The call is `rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2)`. You call the method _on_ the first `Rect` giving the _second `Rect`_ as (only) argument.

Comment: @RenéVogt I am sorry, I am really new to programming, I guess I haven't wrapped my mind around what I am even doing. Do I declare System.Windows.Rect.intersectsWith under my namespace Game?

Comment: @Cinnamonbun you don't need to declare it. You may want to add a `using System.Windows;`  to your file. Then you can use `Rect` as any other type in c#.